# Negating a complex regex

Tags: java, regex, math

I have tried the standard look ahead methods of negating a regex I'm using for an equation solver. The problem is that it isn't working.

Given the sample equation:
1+2x5+3x4

I want to isolate the2 instances of multiplication. I want {1+, +} in one array, and {2x5, 3x4} in the other.

I used split("\\d+x\\d") to get the first array, but can't successfully negate that regex to get the other. Thanks for your time, any help appreciated!

Comment: @LutzL How is that answer directly relevant to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a one-liner which will yield the multiplication terms, but it is fairly straightforward to extract them using a matcher.

```
String input = "1+2x5+3x4";
// you already found a way to identify the non multiplication terms
String[] first = input.split("\\d+x\\d+");

String pattern = "(\\d+x\\d+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    second.add(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Note that in general you should probably be using a *parser* to handle a complex arithmetic expression.  That parser may internally heavily use regex, but using regex alone won't work well as soon as you get nested parentheses.

**Output:**

```
2x5
3x4
```

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks a bunch! I haven't looked at parser yet, but will definitely do so now. I was planning to recurse to deal with parentheses once I defined the basic order of operations. I'll give this a shot!